# Chef: samba cookbook error: No version specified, and no candidate version available for smbclient

Tags: chef-infra, samba, cookbook

When running the opscode samba cookbook I get this error, I have set up my users data bag, my shares data bag as well as my samba user as described in the samba cookbook usage, but still get this message.

```
[2013-09-18T10:56:22-05:00] INFO: *** Chef 10.24.0 ***
[2013-09-18T10:56:25-05:00] INFO: [inet6] no default interface, picking the first ipaddress
[2013-09-18T10:56:26-05:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[samba]]
[2013-09-18T10:56:26-05:00] INFO: Run List expands to [samba]
[2013-09-18T10:56:26-05:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: No routes match the request: /reports/nodes/ChefClient/runs
[2013-09-18T10:56:26-05:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for ChefClient
[2013-09-18T10:56:26-05:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2013-09-18T10:56:26-05:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2013-09-18T10:56:26-05:00] INFO: Loading cookbooks [samba]
[2013-09-18T10:56:26-05:00] INFO: Processing samba_user[erxhub-devtest] action create (samba::default line 19)
[2013-09-18T10:56:26-05:00] INFO: Processing samba_user[erxhub-devtest] action enable (samba::default line 19)
[2013-09-18T10:56:26-05:00] INFO: Processing package[smbclient] action install (samba::client line 23)

================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[smbclient]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::Package
-------------------------
No version specified, and no candidate version available for smbclient

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/samba/recipes/client.rb

 23: )

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/samba/recipes/client.rb:23:in `from_file'

package("smbclient") do
  action :install
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  package_name "smbclient"
  cookbook_name "samba"
  recipe_name "client"
end

[2013-09-18T11:00:07-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-09-18T11:00:10-05:00] FATAL: Saving node information to /var/chef/cache/failed-run-data.json
[2013-09-18T11:00:10-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-09-18T11:00:29-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-09-18T11:00:29-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::Package: package[smbclient] (samba::client line 23) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Package: No version specified, and no candidate version available for smbclient
```

Any insight about what may be happening and what "No version specified, and no candidate version available for smbclient" means?

Answer (score 0):

The "package" resource is not particularly clever or complex- under the hood it shells out to `apt-get`, `yum`, or whatever your distribution's equivalent is. Presumably, your distribution doesn't have anything called 'smbclient' in its repository.

If you added some information about what distribution you were using, I could perhaps add a more precise suggestion, but a fork with [an extra value in the proper file](https://github.com/jtimberman/samba-cookbook/blob/master/recipes/client.rb) might be the best way to go.